# Выделить полигоны, попавшие во фрустум в шейдере

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, шейдеры

Cделал селектирующие лучи( получилось 6 плоскостей) . необходимо теперь закрасить цветом треугольники, которые находятся внутри этой усеченной пирамиды. Как посоветуете это сделать? Подскажите не геометрию, а именно как это программно сделать в шейдере. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Концептуально, вам надо перенести модель в пространство фрустума (которое задается почти как матрица проекции) и выделить все что будет в единичном кубе.

Comment: @Kromster у меня вот такая идея есть сначала на модель добавить текстуру. и потом далее все координаты этой модели отправить в шейдер и там в нем проверять

Comment: Текстура вам не нужна. В вершинном шейдере считаете все трансформации, в фрагментном - задаете цвет в зависимости от расчетного положения фрагмента.

Comment: @Kromster аа тоесть это делать в шейдере не фрустума, а в шейдере модели?

Comment: У вас каша, вы много пар прогуляли? Шейдер модели, естественно.

Comment: @Kromster а не подскажите как получить нормаль плоскости, зная 4 стороны (координаты)плоскости?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75970/discussion-between-kromster-and-).